# forward ssh and ftp with a reverse proxy (squid)

Tags: ssh, ftp, squid

I already have a reverse proxy setup for HTTP, and im now looking to add ssh and ftp to it.

i assume i can just copy the rules from the http list?

how do i go about forwarding the requests? id like to have ftp on port 1235 and ssh on 1236

Answer (score 1):

You talking about the same SSH as I use? [Secure SHell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH)?

AFAIK: nothing to "proxy", no HTTP connections.. impossible.

If you EVER get that working, defo email me or something, cause damn!

This page describes how to reverse proxy FTP: https://calomel.org/ftp_proxy.html

Comment: yeah i wasnt too hopeful when i was reading about ssh before posting the question

Comment: Its an interesting concept though, you can always "Relay".. but not "Proxy" as such. http://serverfault.com/questions/72343/ssh-relay-server-with-openssh

Answer (score 1):

Secure Shell does not use HTTP as a transport.  You won't be able to "proxy" them with Apache/Squid in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not sure that I understand what you ask , but have you tried -R or -D ?