# How to tunneling RDP access and SSL access

Tags: ssh, rdp, tunneling

I need to RDP to a terminal windows server 2003 OS and then RDP from there to my destination remote host. Same thing to SSL, first SSH to a CentOS via putty, then SSH to my destination remote CentOS host.

This is actually 2 different questions but same purpose. Is there any tool that can tunneling my connection, so I can directly RDP/SSH to destination. Thanks.

Comment: See this for the SSH half.  http://serverfault.com/questions/72343/ssh-relay-server-with-openssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [options to mstsc](http://ss64.com/nt/mstsc.html) for exactly what you need, but it should go something like this:

1. Create RDP connection to host1
2. Specify `mstsc host2.rdp` as the program to run
3. Execute `host1.rdp`

If you don't mind having to enter your credentials, you could just use `mstsc /v:host2` in step 2.